# Applications of the fact deformation retracts are closed under pushout

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> **Fact:** Suppose we have a pushout diagram $$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} A @>{f}>> C\\ @V{i}VV @VV{j}V\\ B @>>{g}> D\end{CD}$$
>   where $i$ is the inclusion of a deformation retract. Then $B$ is a deformation retract of $D$.

What are some examples of spaces which are not in any (reasonably) obvious way deformation retracts, but can easily seen to be so using the above fact?

Comment: will the downvoter explain the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an interesting answer for what you are hoping for, since intuitively or geometrically speaking this result makes sense. It is just a more fancy way of saying

> "if you can deformation retract a space $C$ onto a subspace $A$ you can still do so if you attach something along $A$".

Comment: We'll have to wait and see :P